# how to delete a space ( " " ) from a string (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, string

I want to make a for loop to delete a " " space each time it loop across the code. Like I have a string with 5 spaces "     " I want if to 4 then 3 then 2 etc.

Comment: Please provide us what you have tried so far so we can better help you with your homework.

Comment: Dim str As String = "Hello there!"
        Dim result As String = str.Replace(" ", "")  Use "Replace"

Comment: You need to better explain what you're looking to do, with some examples of what you've tried too. Do your spaces that you want to remove on each loop get removed from the left or right of the string?

Comment: can you give sample input and output so we can picture out what you're trying to achieve.